# React native maps working in expo go but not in APK via expo

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I have a problem in react native apk.
My codes in Map is working if Im using expo go. I can see my current location and other functionality inside the maps. So lately, I created an APK app via expo, the EAS build. The APK is working fine because I can change the user's password, but in the APK, esp in map screen, the map wont display.

This is what I tried:

1. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#add-the-api-key-to-your-project
2. My codes in Map

```
 {location && (
        <MapView
          // onMapReady={() => {
          //   orderInformation.forEach((customer) => {
          //     handleMarkerPress(customer);
          //   });
          // }}
          ref={mapRef}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          mapType="hybrid"
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01,
          }}
```

3. my app.json

```
 "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "config":{

        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "mykey"
        }
      },
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ],
 "package": "com.xxxxxxxx.com"
    },
```

and I even edit my API key to add the SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint from Expo credentials.
Thank you.